# MySQL Configuration for Fluent NHibernate

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, fluent

I have class-configurer fluent nhibernate for MySQL:

```
class MySqlInitializer : INHibernateInitializer
{
    public Configuration GetConfiguration()
    {
        var dbServer = "localhost";
        var dbUsername = "root";
        var dbName = "nhibernate";
        var dbPassword = "";
        var ormAssembly = "NHibernate_MySQL.Domain";

        var config = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MySQLConfiguration
                          .Standard
                          .ConnectionString(cs => cs
                                                      .Server(dbServer)
                                                      .Database(dbName)
                                                      .Username(dbUsername)
                                                      .Password(dbPassword)))
            .Mappings(
                x =>
                x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.Load(ormAssembly)));

        return config.BuildConfiguration();
    }
}
```

All data's correct.
So, I also have integration test (Xunit):

```
[Fact]
    public void GenerateMigrationScript()
    {
        var config = new MySqlInitializer().GetConfiguration();
        var factory = (ISessionFactoryImplementor) config.BuildSessionFactory();

        using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
        {
            var updateScripts = config
                .GenerateSchemaUpdateScript(factory.Dialect,
                                            new DatabaseMetadata((DbConnection) session.Connection, factory.Dialect));

            foreach (var updateScript in updateScripts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(updateScript + ";");
            }
        }
    }
```

My entities:

```
public interface IHiberEntutyBase
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class HiberEntity : IHiberEntutyBase
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

class HiberEntityMap : ClassMap<HiberEntity>
{
    public HiberEntityMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();

        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

When I runs GenerateMigrationScript() writes "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown database 'nhibernate'".
Help me please.

Answer (score 3):

It means what it says: you don't have a database called "nhibernate".

NHibernate does not create databases, only schemas (tables, keys). The database must exist.