# FluentNHibernate MySQL configuration

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, visual-studio-2013, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to configure the session factory for mySQL but I the Standard function is not working

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point here is the upper/lower case *(**SQL** vs **Sql**)*:

```
// wrong
MySqlConfiguration // Sql
// MUST Be 
MySQLConfiguration // SQL
```

Check the similar Q & A:

- [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'Standard' Fluent NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14586733/1679310)

Here is Question with some snippet showing the right upper/lower case:

- [MySQL Configuration for Fluent NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4045646/1679310)